# capistrano addresses wrong server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

This is my script

```
require "bundler/capistrano"  
set :bundle_without, [:development, :test, :deployment]  
require "delayed/recipes" unless exists?(:ip)  
set :stages, %w(production staging dev)  
set :default_stage, "staging"  
require "capistrano/ext/multistage"  
set :rvm_type, :user  
require "rvm/capistrano"  

load "config/recipes/nginx"  
load "config/recipes/passenger"  
load "config/recipes/deploy"  
load "config/recipes/symlink"  

set :application, "dev"  
set :keep_releases, 5  
set :deploy_server,  'IP'    
  role :web,            deploy_server  
  role :app,            deploy_server  
  role :db,             deploy_server, :primary => true  
set :port, 222  
set :user, "user"  
set :use_sudo, false  


set :scm, :git  
set :repository, "git@github.com:a/b.git"  
set :branch, "master" unless exists?(:branch)  
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache  
set :copy_exclude, [ '.git' ]  
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/#{application}"  
set :rails_env, "production" unless exists?(:rails_env)  

set :normalize_asset_timestamps, false  

ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true  
on :start do  
  `ssh-add`  
end
```

and console's output is:

```
% cap deploy  
    triggering load callbacks  
  * 2014-06-19 17:40:13 executing `staging'  
    triggering start callbacks for `deploy'  
  * 2014-06-19 17:40:13 executing `multistage:ensure'  
Enter passphrase for /Users/password123/.ssh/id_rsa:  
Identity added: /Users/password123/.ssh/id_rsa (/Users/password123/.ssh/id_rsa)  
  * 2014-06-19 17:40:16 executing `deploy'  
    triggering before callbacks for `deploy'  
  * 2014-06-19 17:40:16 executing `deploy:setup'  
  * executing "mkdir -p /var/www/core.dev /var/www/core.dev/releases /var/www/core.dev/shared /var/www/core.dev/shared/system /var/www/core.dev/shared/log /var/www/core.dev/shared/pids"  
    servers: ["IP", "193.84.22.52"]
Password:  
connection failed for: 193.84.22.52 (Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Operation timed out - connect(2))
```

I can't find where it's set.

And have no idea from where it appears. Files which are loaded in this script contain inserver operations. could you help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your default stage is set to `staging`, take a look in `config/deploy/staging.rb`.